# CSV import in PGAdmin 4 failed

Tags: postgresql, csv, pgadmin-4

I am trying to import a csv file into my postgreSQL database with pgAdmin4, with Import/Export.
It does not work and I didn't found the solution on forums.
[image: import csv with pgAdmin4]
Here is my error : "Additional data after the assumed last column"
[image: Error while importing csv]

And here is my csv format, with comma :
[image: csv format used]

I also tried with `|` instead of `comma`.
Even when I delete the header, it still says the same, which is strange I think (how should it know how many columns there are).

**EDIT**

Here is my empty table waiting to be filled :

```
--
-- PostgreSQL database dump
--

-- Dumped from database version 10.3
-- Dumped by pg_dump version 10.3

-- Started on 2018-05-24 09:23:17

SET statement_timeout = 0;
SET lock_timeout = 0;
SET idle_in_transaction_session_timeout = 0;
SET client_encoding = 'UTF8';
SET standard_conforming_strings = on;
SELECT pg_catalog.set_config('search_path', '', false);
SET check_function_bodies = false;
SET client_min_messages = warning;
SET row_security = off;

SET default_tablespace = '';

SET default_with_oids = false;

--
-- TOC entry 219 (class 1259 OID 21131)
-- Name: ouvrages_complet; Type: TABLE; Schema: public; Owner: postgres
--

CREATE TABLE public.ouvrages_complet (
    numrow integer,
    "Chute_etiage" double precision,
    "Statut" text,
    "Classement" text,
    "Commentaires" text,
    "Elements_mobiles" text
)
INHERITS (public.ouvrages);


ALTER TABLE public.ouvrages_complet OWNER TO postgres;

--
-- TOC entry 4066 (class 2604 OID 21134)
-- Name: ouvrages_complet gid; Type: DEFAULT; Schema: public; Owner: postgres
--

ALTER TABLE ONLY public.ouvrages_complet ALTER COLUMN gid SET DEFAULT nextval('public.ouvrages_gid_seq1'::regclass);


--
-- TOC entry 4195 (class 0 OID 21131)
-- Dependencies: 219
-- Data for Name: ouvrages_complet; Type: TABLE DATA; Schema: public; Owner: postgres
--

COPY public.ouvrages_complet (gid, field1, idroe, dep, courseau, masseeau, espece, nom, commune, syndicat, xl93, yl93, coefsat, notecoef, regproprio, notereg, mortdeval, notemortd, projet, noteprojet, proprio, positprop, noteposit, distconfl, gainkmouv, notegain, passepoiss, precpasse, systmont, notesysm, systdev, notesysd, usage, presenceus, noteusage, etat, noteetat, notetot, impact, anneemaj, cominsee, typeouvr, sstypeouvr, geom, franchiss, numrow, "Chute_etiage", "Statut", "Classement", "Commentaires", "Elements_mobiles") FROM stdin;
\.


-- Completed on 2018-05-24 09:23:17

--
-- PostgreSQL database dump complete
--
```

And here is my csv file :
[Link to the csv table](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Lt1ySNRkVndJvdxjhE4W9nRakN6BWalR)

Comment: Can you post some sample data and the create table statement? My first guess would be that the columns do not match.

Comment: Post some actual data, not a picture of the data.

Comment: Can you please provide table definition of yours in which you try to import the data? I suspect mismatch in the columns you selected and the csv data you are trying to import.

Comment: I didn't create an empty table, I though it was not necessary, then I did it. I post it and the csv file as an edit.

Comment: by the way, the error is still the same with the empty table created